# Error "An item with the same key has already been added" when I try to pass an object from the filter to controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I would like to pass an object form my filter to the controller. I will show you my code:

Filter:

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
        {
            var customerRepository = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService<ICustomerRepository>();

            var authHeader = context.HttpContext.Request?.Headers["Authorization"].ToString();

            if (!Int32.TryParse(authHeader, out int clientId))
            {
                context.Result = new UnauthorizedResult();
            }

            var customer = customerRepository.Get(x => x.CustomerId == clientId, typeof(Application).Name);

            if (customer == null)
            {
                context.Result = new UnauthorizedResult();
            }

            context.ActionArguments.Add("Customer", customer);
        }
```

Controller:

```
[Route("/api/v1.0/startup")]
[IncludeCustomerToHttpContext]
[HttpPatch]
public async Task<IActionResult> Update([FromBody] CustomerChangeViewModel viewModel, Customer customer)
{
    ...
}
```

But when I run my application I have the following error:

> System.ArgumentException: An item with the same key has already been added. Key: Customer

Why it's happening? What is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ActionArguments` implements `IDictionary`. You are calling the [Add](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.idictionary-2.add?view=netcore-3.1) method which can throw an `ArgumentException` when you try to add a key-value pair into the dictionary where the key is already present:

> ArgumentException
>   An element with the same key already exists in the IDictionary.

If you want to override a previous value, you can simply assign the value to the `ActionArguments` dictionary via the indexer.

Use

```
context.ActionArguments["Customer"] = customer;
```

instead

Comment: Thank you very much! It works. But could you explain why I already had value in the  `context.ActionArguments`? I had only one row `context.ActionArguments.Add("Customer", customer)`.

Comment: Your `Update` method has a parameter called `Customer customer` as well

Comment: Now I understand. `public async Task<IActionResult> Update([FromBody] CustomerChangeViewModel viewModel, Customer customer)` This signature will create for me `context.ActionArguments.Add("Customer", customer);` before my filter, right?

Comment: Something like that. Basically, you gain access to the parameters of your method and you already have a `customer` parameter there. I don't think that that line is being called internally, but rather that the ActionArguments use the same Dictionary